# Centos image build fails when I use rpms via docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm currently working out a Dockerfile. So I am trying to build out a Centos 7.6 base image and I get a failure when I try to use any yum packages. I'm not sure what the cause of this is.

I've already attempted to make the user root to see if that makes a difference but it doesn't help the situation. I've also done a `docker pull centos` to recieve the latest version of centos.

I simplified the code and still the same error.

```
FROM centos
ARG MONGO-RAILS-VERSION="0.0"

RUN yum install vim
#    curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable \
#    rvm install 2.3.1 \
#    rvm use 2.3.1 --default \
#    gem install rails
```

I get an error that looks something like this

```
 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:1b48:203::4:10: Network is unreachable"
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install vim' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Not a solution, but a starting point: "Failed to connect to 2001:1b48:203::4:10:" suggests it's trying to connect over IPv6, and maybe you don't have IPv6?

Comment: Do you have proxy to visit internet?

Comment: @atline yes I have to proxy to visit the internet

Comment: So, proxy was added when you build dockerfile or nothing added?

Comment: No I proxied prior to building the image. Something like this https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-docker-to-use-proxy/

Comment: @atline yes I added a proxy as a build time variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look for [Set build-time variables (--build-arg)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg):

```
$ docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234 --build-arg FTP_PROXY=http://40.50.60.5:4567 .
```